# Android: Designing for MySQL and SQLite database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, activerecord, orm

So as the title says, I'm creating an Android application with an SQLite database. This database will be synchronized with a MySQL database connected to a homepage (and also in the future the MySQL database will be used in conjunction with IPhone).

If the user makes a change on the android system or the MySQL database it will synchronize the data between the two when an internet connection is available.

The first question is - How will I be able to know which one of the databases that contains the last version? I cannot trust the timestamp since anyone can change the time-setting on their phone, right?

The second question is more of a design-issue, see the attached image:

[image: UML-diagram User Data Access Object and Model]

The current plan for the design is using some kind of DataAccessObject pattern, which will help me with the data access, the SQLiteDb will be used for speed the first time a listview (for instance) is showed to the user and it will be updated in the background by the HttpUserDAO.

I've got the feeling that this is not "good design" - coming from PHP when I'm used to work with Doctrine2 this just feels wrong somehow.

Is there any other pattern I should read up on, when handling the database and objects? (I'd like to stay away from ORM frameworks right now to have some more control myself) Or should I just use pure data access objects without building the model objects? Any tips? I get stuck when using data access objects or active record when trying to design for "objects owning objects" that should be saved to the database.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question about "most recent data" - you should be able to access GMT time on the device and the server. Although the user or the device may report this inaccurately, if you normalize to GMT (drop timezone changes and day saving time adjustments), you will have the most reliable time indicator. Also, you can also include things like "record number" and verify that against recent updates and whether or not the GMT timestamp is similar to other updates being made. You can also have "invalid record data" responses for data that seems suspicious. If the user messes with GMT settings in some way, you can build monitoring into your updates to see if the updates "make sense" - but mostly, this is unlikely to happen. A GMT timestamp is usually sufficient.

On your "design" question, you need a "system of record" or SOR - in other words, the device database should be the SOR for display. If your HTTP object indicates that the SOR is out of date, it should update the SOR on the device because your server is the SOR for centralized data. Once the update to the device SOR is complete, it should notify the display that the data has been modified and needs to be refreshed.

You are correct - your model indicates that there is a problem. You cannot have the display rely on two data sources simultaneously. The pattern described above will work in nearly all cases. If it does not work (like for a stock trading app), then you need to eliminate the problem (in the case of a stock trading app, device records for prices can easily age, so you remove the device SOR and display a "data not available" message when an HTTP connection cannot be established).

EDIT:

`Cursor`s handle binding to the database by having methods like `registerContentObserver` and `setNotificationUri`. In other words, the issue for data consistency comes down to the urgency/importance of the data. If the core data changes but the display does not, what problems does that create? In your case, you should probably implement some kind of similar registration for changes. That registration can include a long series of possible methods (like "data out of sync" and "synchronizing data" and "updating data" etc.). Basically, it requires creating a listener interface that an object can register, and then selecting which data in the database will be monitored. Then simply send notifications to those listeners when any event occurs that you are interested in monitoring.

For example, you can have your HTTP DAO notify that an update is in progress by having an "updateInProgress" registration. If you only care after data has been updated, then after an update to a table in your database, you can have a "datasetChanged" listener notification.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. I'm not putting this as the accepted one yet since I'm stil looking for tips on how to handle the object <-> binding when a object has another object that also is available in the database (recursive, object handling?) ORM solves this issue perfectly using Doctrine2 but using cascading. - What is the "typical" way to handle advanced object <-> database bindings? when not using an ORM? is there any design pattern or should I use database calls directly without binding them to objects? do you have any tips on this? design patterns?

Comment: Cascading is one method of handling this. Since you are implementing your own system, you should first consider your use-case. I've edited my answer to provide a generic "data is out of date" notification concept. In most cases, you can simply notify that the dataset has changed after the change is complete.